# MySql JSON encoding issue

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I've got a MySql database. The tables in it are defined with `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`. However, the data in the tables seem to be miscoded.

`SELECT json_object('x', textfield) AS test FROM MyTable LIMIT 1;`

```
+-----------------------------+
| test                        |
+-----------------------------+
| {"x": "This isnâ€™t right"} |
+-----------------------------+
```

How do I convert the text in the table to the right encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Mojibake

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.  (You say they were.)

What is your client?  If it is the "mysql commandline tool" (as it appears to be), perform `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting.

After that, if the `isn’t` comes out as `isn?t`, see [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#entering_accents_in_cmd).